# Show that if $|g'(x)|\le M|x-a|^n$ for $|x-a|\lt \delta$, then $|g(x)-g(a)|\le M|x-a|^{n+1}/(n+1)$ for $|x-a|\lt \delta$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Problem:

Show that if $|g'(x)|\le M|x-a|^n$ for $|x-a|\lt \delta$, then $|g(x)-g(a)|\le M|x-a|^{n+1}/(n+1)$ for $|x-a|\lt \delta$.

Solution:

[image]

I have difficulty understanding this solution. Applying the Mean Value Theorem, I get, $|g(x)-g(a)|=|(x-a)||g'(t)|\le M|x-a|^{n+1}$. I don't see where the $n+1$ in the denominator comes from. I tried solving this by integrating both sides $\int_a^x$, but then this only works if $g'$ is integrable on $[a,x]$, which is not a given condition on this problem. What am I getting wrong here? I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*
A variant version of the mean-value theorem takes place, which may be more essential than the usual version: Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$; let $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $]a,b[$; let $h: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $]a,b[$; let $|g'(x)| \leq h'(x)$ for all $x \in ]a,b[$; then $|g(b)-g(a)| \leq h(b) - h(a)$.

Take $h: x \mapsto M(x-a)^{n+1}/(n+1)$; then the result follows.

Comment: Could you provide a proof of this variant version?

Comment: @takecare: Somewhat lengthy; you may be referred to H. Cartan's differential calculus, say. :) There you will see a more general version than the present one.

Comment: I checked the theorem from Cartan's text, but is there any other more elementary way? Because the text I got this problem and solution from does not discuss such advanced theorems...

Comment: @takecare: Good for you; I am afraid I am not sure about if there is any elementary way, and for now I have no time to try to work out an elementary way :) Maybe you can try to ask another question; anyway, I think the present information is sufficient for answering the present question.